# Deploying Virtual Machines Using Salt and Salt-Virt on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, saltstack

I am using Salt to provision machines, both physical and virtual, for my company. It would be really nice if I could also use Salt (Salt-Virt) to manage the various virtual machines running on my hosts, as the number/complexity of VMs is growing quickly.

Here's where I am:

- Followed this guide, changing packages for Ubuntu instead of RHL: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/cloud_controller.html
- Both the physical and virtual machines are running Ubuntu Server
- I am able to run the `salt-run virt.init test1 2 512 salt://BASE.img` command to deploy the machine to the host.
- The image is showing up on the minion in `/srv/salt-images/test1/` as a .qcow2

But it seems that the host (hypervisor) has no idea that the VM exists. I am not getting any errors from Salt on the master or the minion.

- On the host, `virsh list` brings back an empty list
- On the Salt master, `salt-run virt.start test1` returns the error: `Failed to find vm test1 to start`

Has anyone ever gotten Salt-Virt to work on Ubuntu? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Here are the steps:

- Two machines, M1 and M2
- On M1:

  - Install salt master
  - Move your virtual hard drive to this machine, place it in `/srv/salt`

    - For me, this was `/srv/salt/base.vdi`
  - **Convert the virtual machine file to qcow2 format**

    - For me, this was `qemu-img -f vdi -O qcow2 base.vdi base.qcow2`
- On M2:

  - Install salt minion
  - Install libvirt-bin
  - Install python-libvirt
  - configure a bridged network interface called `br0`

    - This is important, because that is the default interface name to which salt-virt attaches VMs

Cool. The machines should be ready to go now.

On the master, run `salt "*" virt.init <name_of_vm> <num_cores_for_vm> <mb_of_ram_for_vm> <path_to_image>`

For me, this was `salt "*" virt.init test_vm 2 512 salt://base.qcow2`

Machine should spin up on M2.

Test using `salt-run virt.query` on the salt master